# Android SDK TO Adobe Air

Tags: android, flash, actionscript

We have Some native android SDK libraries ,  now we need to use them in Adobe Air (android) app   with Flash Builder, Is that possible to somehow integrate them and use them inside FlashBuilder project  with ActionScript  ?

Comment: Yes. You need to create ANE(Air Native Extensions) in java, and import them to AIR project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [Air Native Extension](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html) to do that.
The ANE framework gives you a bridge that lets you interface your Actionscript code with native libraries, your Android jar library in this case.

Once you successfully built the extension you can use it as any other swc library in FlashBuilder or other IDE.